# I am trying to write a code for AVL insertion

Tags: python, data-structures, tree, avl-tree, insertion

I am aware that there are certain methods to create an AVL tree online. However, I am trying to do it with a different method. The problem that I am facing is that I can not spot where does it goes wrong after rotation.

I have added the code that I have been writing. It rearranges the leaves after rotation, but some of the child nodes of the re-arranged nodes, ends up being lost and thus don't remain part of the tree anymore. Help me find where does the issue lie.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.height = 0


class AVLTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self, value):
        obj = Node(value)
        temp_list = []
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = obj
            temp_list.append(self.root)
            temp_list[0].height = self.update_height(temp_list[0])
        else:
            temp_list.append(self.root)
            while temp_list:
                if temp_list[0].data >= value:
                    if temp_list[0].left is None:
                        temp_list[0].left = obj
                    elif temp_list[0].left is not None:
                        temp_list.append(temp_list[0].left)
                elif temp_list[0].data < value:
                    if temp_list[0].right is None:
                        temp_list[0].right = obj
                    elif temp_list[0].right is not None:
                        temp_list.append(temp_list[0].right)
                self.update_all_height()
                temp_list.remove(temp_list[0])

            # Balance Factor
            root = self.root
            temp_lst = [root]
            temp_lst[0].height = self.update_height(temp_lst[0])
            while temp_lst:
                if root.left is not None:
                    temp_lst.append(root.left)
                if root.right is not None:
                    temp_lst.append(root.right)
                node = self.find_balance_node()
                balance_factor = self.get_bf(node)

                if balance_factor is None:
                    break
                else:
                    print("Node: ", node.data, "balance factor: ", balance_factor)
                    if balance_factor > 1:
                        if value < temp_lst[0].left.data:
                            print("LL")
                            return self.single_left_rotation(self.find_balance_node())
                        elif value > temp_lst[0].left.data:
                            print("LR")
                            return self.double_left_right_rotation(self.find_balance_node())
                    elif balance_factor < -1:
                        if value > temp_lst[0].right.data:
                            print("RR")
                            return self.single_right_rotation(self.find_balance_node())
                        elif value < temp_lst[0].right.data:
                            print("RL")
                            return self.double_right_left_rotation(self.find_balance_node())

                    temp_lst.remove(temp_lst[0])
                    if len(temp_lst) > 0:
                        root = temp_lst[0]

    def update_height(self, N):
        if N is None:
            return 0
        return 1 + max(self.update_height(N.left), self.update_height(N.right))

    def update_all_height(self):
        root = self.root
        temp_lst = [root]
        temp_lst[0].height = self.update_height(temp_lst[0])
        while temp_lst:
            if root.left is not None:
                temp_lst.append(root.left)
            if root.right is not None:
                temp_lst.append(root.right)
            temp_lst[0].height = self.update_height(temp_lst[0])
            temp_lst.remove(temp_lst[0])
            if len(temp_lst) > 0:
                root = temp_lst[0]

    def find_balance_node(self):
        the_node = None
        the_lst = []
        root = self.root
        temp_lst = [root]
        while temp_lst:
            if root.left is not None:
                temp_lst.append(root.left)
            if root.right is not None:
                temp_lst.append(root.right)
            lst = [0, 1, -1]
            print(self.get_bf(temp_lst[0]), temp_lst[0].data)
            if self.get_bf(temp_lst[0]) not in lst:
                the_lst.append(temp_lst[0])
                the_node = temp_lst[0]
            temp_lst.remove(temp_lst[0])
            if len(temp_lst) > 0:
                root = temp_lst[0]
        if the_node is not None:
            # print("\nWELL WE FOUND THE NODE", the_node.data)
        return the_node

    def get_bf(self, root):
        if root is None:
            return
        return self.get_height(root.left) - self.get_height(root.right)

    def get_height(self, N):
        if N is None:
            return 0
        return N.height

    def single_right_rotation(self, N):
        # print("RR")
        Y = N.right
        T = Y.left
        Y.left = N
        N.right = T
        N.height = 1 + max(self.get_height(N.left), self.get_height(N.right))
        Y.height = 1 + max(self.get_height(Y.left), self.get_height(Y.right))
        return Y

    def single_left_rotation(self, N):
        print("LL")
        Y = N.left
        T = Y.right
        Y.right = N
        N.left = T
        N.height = 1 + max(self.get_height(N.left), self.get_height(N.right))
        Y.height = 1 + max(self.get_height(Y.left), self.get_height(Y.right))
        return Y

    def double_left_right_rotation(self, N):
        print("LR")
        N.left = self.single_right_rotation(N.left)
        return self.single_left_rotation(N)

    def double_right_left_rotation(self, N):
        print("RL")
        N.right = self.single_left_rotation(N.right)
        return self.single_right_rotation(N)

    def breadth_first_traversal(self):
        root = self.root
        temp_lst = []
        temp_lst.append(root)
        while temp_lst:
            if root.left is not None:
                temp_lst.append(root.left)
            if root.right is not None:
                temp_lst.append(root.right)
            print("this ", temp_lst[0].data, temp_lst[0].height)
            temp_lst.remove(temp_lst[0])
            if len(temp_lst) > 0:
                root = temp_lst[0]


def main():
    bst = AVLTree()
    bst.insert(100)
    bst.insert(120)
    bst.insert(20)
    bst.insert(10)
    bst.insert(15)

    bst.breadth_first_traversal()


main()
```

Comment: Construct the simplest possible example tree where you lose data, then look at what is lost. Most likely you're not correctly assigning the new root after a rotation somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

While rotation you are losing data since reference from parent to rotating point is not changed.

For example :

Insertion of 10 in below figure should cause rotation at 20. As per code Rotation at 20 happened but 100 still have child as 20 (pointer from 100 did not change).
100 should point to 15 but code is not able to handle this scenario.

```
        100         
        / \                     
       20  120   --->     15   100
      /                   / \  / \
     15                  10  20   120
    /
   10
```

So if the tree is traversed after inserting 10, then it will give (inorder traversal): 20 100 120 , since 100 is still pointing to 20 even after rotation.

To solve the issue either perform some kind of swapping in the rotation or handle rotation from parent. Both are more complicated then recursive solution.